# Left join not working in my prepared statement (mysqli)

Tags: php, mysql

I can't get a left join to work in my prepared statement.

```
"SELECT DISTINCT(a.auto_id), m.merk, a.model, a.uitvoering, a.standaardtekst, a.prijs, a.prijs2, a.prijs3, a.handelsprijs, a.aanmaak, s.soort, z.prijs_id
/*,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(apc.NL) ORDER BY apc.NL ASC)*/

FROM autocom_new.auto_new a
INNER JOIN autocom_new.tbl_merken m
ON a.merk = m.merk_id
INNER JOIN autocom_new.tbl_soort s
ON a.soort = s.soort_id
INNER JOIN autocom_new.auto_zoekmachines z
ON a.auto_id = z.auto_id

/*
LEFT JOIN autocom_new.auto_accessoire acc
ON a.auto_id = acc.auto_id
LEFT JOIN autocom_new.tbl_autopricecode_new apc
ON acc.code_id = apc.code_id
*/

WHERE a.ac LIKE ? AND a.flag = ?"
```

The commented parts are the parts that aren't working. 
I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT**
First of all I forgot that both tables have a column ac, so I've changed the where statement a bit. The left joins are working now, but the part in the select is still not working

Comment: There is no relation between joins and prepared statements. Any query that works raw, works when prepared as well. So, debug your SQL.

Comment: If i only execute the query it will give me 1 row. ( which should be more) and if I put this query in the prepared statement, I'll get no row at all

Comment: Please show table definitions, primary and foreign keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that I forgot a GROUP BY.

```
"SELECT DISTINCT(a.auto_id), m.merk, a.model, a.uitvoering, a.standaardtekst, a.prijs, a.prijs2, a.prijs3, a.handelsprijs, a.aanmaak, s.soort, z.prijs_id,
 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(apc.NL) ORDER BY apc.NL ASC)

 FROM autocom_new.auto_new a
 INNER JOIN autocom_new.tbl_merken m
 ON a.merk = m.merk_id
 INNER JOIN autocom_new.tbl_soort s
 ON a.soort = s.soort_id
 INNER JOIN autocom_new.auto_zoekmachines z
 ON a.auto_id = z.auto_id

 LEFT JOIN autocom_new.auto_accessoire acc
 ON a.auto_id = acc.auto_id

 LEFT JOIN autocom_new.tbl_autopricecode_new apc
 ON acc.code_id = apc.code_id

 WHERE a.ac LIKE ? AND a.flag = ?
 GROUP BY a.auto_id"
```